# Malicious port scanners: do they target machines that they know exist even if they're powered off?

Tags: router, security

I set up my ageing Netgear (circa 2007) router to send email security logs quite a long time ago, and then never really looked at them or fully understood what they meant.

I was doing a general sweep of my security the other day, and I decided to try to understand what the router logs were telling me.

For instance, here's a line item from the log sent a few days ago (I've obscured the IP addresses):

Tue, 2014-11-25 05:44:18 - TCP Packet - Source:XX.XX.XXX.XX Destination:YYY.YYY.Y.Y - [RDP match]

I'm assuming the [RDP match] means it was looking to see if it could do an RDP connection (the Netgear documentation is pretty scant on information).

The thing is, the machine at Destination IP address was powered off at that time in the morning.

What gives? Does some port scanner somewhere know that there's a machine on my network at that IP address and just tries it anyway, or have I got it all wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's incorrect to assume a remote port scan has prior knowledge of your machine's existence in the first place. Your log is misleading you to think the scan targeted your computer *behind* the firewall, when in fact the remote computer only knows the IP address of the firewall's public IP. The log is "helpfully" telling you what internal IP this packet would have been forwarded to, but that info should not be extended to mean the attacker *knew* where the packet would be forwarded (or even *if* it would be).

Comment: Great, thanks for that. Doing some more reading on it after I made the post had me thinking that was the case, but it's good to have it confirmed.

Comment: Yes, the reality of *constant* remote logon attempts is very real. For this reason one must 1) Open only those doors absolutely needed, 2) Always use very strong, very long passwords for any account that can be used to connect remotely [even if it's an account with no administrator privileges], and 3) Install the latest security patches for everything with the attitude that an unpatched system is the same as one where all of the passwords are `password123` [because it's true](https://www.duosecurity.com/blog/duo-security-researchers-uncover-bypass-of-paypal-s-two-factor-authentication)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is somewhat speculative, due to lack of knowlege of your specific router and it's configuration.

The log message may mean that the router logged the packet as being let through it's NAT and/or firewall on the basis that it matches the criteria for a rule related to the RDP protocol.

If the target machine were off, the router may still attempt to send the packet on to the target machine, however the packet would receive no further processing due to the machine being off and thus any RDP connection should fail.

If the machine were on, any further processing would depend on local firewall rules, as well as the configuration of Remote Desktop on the target machine.

Comment: Thanks. I just did a test, where I RDP'd in using my phone. The phone's IP showed up as the source, and the machine showed up as the destination. I HAD thought that this log showed only blocked packets, but obviously not, because this was a successful attempt that showed up. I don't think I need to worry because the logs show the same stuff from back when I only had the Home version of Windows that didn't even have RDP hosting available, though. AFAIK, port scanning etc. is just something we all have to live with, right?

Comment: Port scanning is a fact of life for internet-facing devices. As long as you're sensible about the traffic you allow through the router, and the services running on machines, you should be OK

Comment: That's what I thought. I'll just turn off Allow RDP to be safe. though.